# How to programmatically create a node when a payment is successful

Tags: 6, ubercart

I have a content type, and  with the help of the UC node checkout module, I am able to successfully add the content to cart once it is created by the user. When the user checked out and had made a successful payment, I want to create another node of another content type.

```
function gy_mod_uc_checkout_complete($order, $account) { 
  if ($order->order_status == 'payment_received') { 
    exit(); 
  } 
}
```

The above is not getting fired; I always get it as "in_checkout." I tried doing it using the Paypal sandbox.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how I should write the code I need?

Comment: The order status is still in pending(post_checkout) once the user completes the payment on paypal. How can i do something on successfull payments? instead of checking the paypal account manually and verify if the payment is successful and change the state as payment_received for the order ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `hook_uc_checkout_complete()` is called while the order is still in "in_checkout."

You might want to consider using Ubercart's *Conditional actions* module and add an action for "Trigger: Customer completes checkout"; it allows you to execute actions based on a range of conditions. You can then either execute custom PHP code to create the node, or implement the `hook_ca_action()` (see "ubercart/ca/ca.ca.inc" for reference).

As to how to programmatically create a node, you can either use [node_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_save/6) or [drupal_execute()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/drupal_execute/6). There's quite a few tutorials around that you can use as guidance.

Comment: Worked for me. TQ