# Create a content type after checking out a product

Tags: 7, nodes, ubercart

I am using Ubercart and I want to create a certain content type after a user checks out a different content type. I'm having the same problem with [How to programmatically create a node when a payment is successful](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8507) but the conversation seems to be too short that I wasn't able to understand what was going on. I'm new to Drupal development, I hope someone might be able to clarify this for me.

Comment: The way I understand it, your question is a duplicate of the one you've linked too. The right thing to do is to continue the conversation on the existing question, not open a new one.

Comment: Hello. This site is **not for conversations**, it is for questions and answers. If you tried the answers under the linked question and still don't understand, show us what have **you** tried and describe how is it problematic for **you**. Until then, I agree with @Letharion, this question is a duplicate.